# Server handling multiple client

Tags: java, multithreading, networking

I'm using ServerSocket for creating a server.
I must create a new thread for each client or is it possible&safe to use only the server's thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just use the server's main thread, then only one client will ever be able to connect, becuase the thread is busy with the only client connected. After that client disconnects, the server can take another client, but you want to be able to accept clients constantly. Thus you need to spawn a thread for each client.

Comment: Thanks for the explanaton =)

Answer (score 1):

If you use only the server thread you will be able to manage only one client for time. I suggest you to use [Executors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html) class in order to create a pool of thread. The pool thread can manage multiple connection like the [ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) javadoc shows.